# User Experience - Design _ need advice on Slants and Colors

Tags: responsive-design

I am not a UX Designer but an UI Programmer and want to get an opinion which will help me articulate the Design Choices my Company should not take

[image]

[image]

As you see from above , there are containers with angled edges which confine the shades. The header [ containing the logo ] part has white background and to the left starts the shade of different color.

A B C are Glypicons

The shading extend to Hero Image.

Also at the end of the page there is container holding the icon.

This whole page should be Responsive - including the shaded container which should change as per device width.

---

I have seen many Pages and they all have a very symmetrical layout and a uniform color background for each of the containers like Header , Hero or other content. 
This looks visually appealing as per my opinion

Take for example in my case the Line dissects hero image and I have to make sure that it cuts the image at the same place in all devices.

How should i convince the Company to have more uniform color palette across each of the container.

For example [Simple Bank](https://www.simple.com/) has a beautiful design.

Please help me out here.

Comment: This looks like a graphic design problem rather than a user experience problem. What the user problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the graphic design stackexchange site but I only have the option to suggest the UX Meta site

Comment: UX problem is that what looks more convenient to the eye.. whether angle shades serve any purpose or a uniform palette looks better

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question here.. Are you looking for arguments against using this layout/design? I don't see anything necessarily wrong with the layout. It is a bit 'messy' and inconsistent, but it is a very rough wireframe so that doesn't say much.

Comment: Depens greatly on what the hero image is

Comment: @CAI _ its a rough wireframe - but a very true representation of the actual website .. POsting a Screen Shot here

Answer (score -1):

I think the actual question is: From a UX standpoint, will angled shadows across various page sections do anything helpful or beneficial? My answer to that is: No, it won't.

The question from a Graphic Design standpoint is: Will angled shadows across various page sections help to unify the design and communicate the intended messaging any better? My answer to that is: No, it won't.

But, the real issue is that your client stakeholders want angled shadows across various page elements. They think it's neat. So, maybe you bite the bullet and do what they want, or convince them that less is more.

Comment: "My answer to that is: No, it won't" How can you say that? Are you saying you should never use angles in design? Angles can be a very useful tool for communicating, but theres no way of knowing what would be good for OPs case from the information given.

Comment: @CAI, I'm not saying angles should never be used. I'm saying that they won't automatically improve the UX or the design. They should be used on purpose, for a specific reason. Based on the information given, they seem to have been requested by the client, and user1428716 is looking for a reason not use them. This is my reason.

In certain cases, for specific reasons, angles can certainly do a lot to improve a design. The designer in this case, user1428716, seems to think they don't improve the design, but wants the wording to explain why. To which I would say, "Less is more."

Comment: OP specifically says he is a developer and not a designer so it's not entirely clear what the situation is. And just because angles may or may not help isn't enough of a reason to say it doesn't work. There's not enough information to say anything either way.

Comment: OP says he wants "to get an opinion which will help me articulate the Design Choices my Company should not take." The situation seems very clear. He's looking for an opinion, and I shared mine. He wants to articulate why this is a design choice they should not take. I did my best to explain why: because the angled shadows don't add any specific benefit on purpose, for a specific reason. In some cases they could, but with the limited information we have, they don't. @CAI, thanks for the dialogue; I appreciate hearing your point of view about it. Just clarifying why my own answer is also valid.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly that clarifies why your answer is valid...